# Pandoc: Converting markdown to HTML, syntax highlighter

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm converting markdown to HTML, and I want to include syntax-highlighted code.

I'm working from some markdown that contains syntax like:

```
  ~~~ {.c}
  long factorial (int n)
  {
    long result = 1;
    while (n > 1)
      result *= n--;
    return result;
  }
  ~~~
```

but I don't know which syntax highlighting extension was used to process this syntax. What's a good extension?

Comment: Pandoc does syntax highlighting automatically.  You don't need an external extension.  Just be sure to use the `-s` flag so you get a standalane HTML file with the CSS needed for highlighting.  You can also use the `--highlight-style` option to adjust the coloring scheme.  Note:  These comments assume you're using the latest pandoc, 1.9.4.2.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why a $HOME/.pandoc folder wasn't automatically generated? When I try to use either option, I get the error `pandoc: slidy: openFile: does not exist`.

Comment: `$HOME/.pandoc` is not automatically generated.  You can add it if you want it, but it is not needed for normal operation.  What command did you use to get the error message you quote?

Comment: When I add the `-s` option, I get this error message: `pandoc -m -t -s slidy  7-functional-design.md -o 7-functional-design.hpart`. I get the same error message if I try adding `--highlight-style=haddock` instead.

Comment: You want `-s -t slidy` instead of `-t -s slidy`.  `slidy` is the argument for the `-t` option and needs to come right after it.

Comment: Thanks, but I discovered that broke the formatting (the words would hover on top of the bullet points. Also, is there a way I can specify the syntax highlighting for different languages?

Comment: The syntax highlighting specified in command line when using pandoc is served as a on/off switch. Don't confuse it with the syntax highlighting for different languages.    To set syntax highlighting for different language, write the language name in your **file**, something like this: `~~~~ruby`

Answer (score 4):

> > > Answer from comments, please edit before giving negative rating.

## Solution

Pandoc does syntax highlighting automatically. You don't need an external extension.

Just be sure to use the `-s` flag so you get a standalane HTML file with the CSS needed for highlighting. You can also use the `--highlight-style` option to adjust the coloring scheme.

***Note: These comments assume you're using the latest `pandoc, 1.9.4.2.`***

> When I add the `-s` option, I get this error message: `pandoc -m -t -s slidy 7-functional-design.md -o 7-functional-design.hpart`. I get the same error message if I try adding `--highlight-style=haddock` instead.

You want `-s -t slidy` instead of `-t -s slidy`.

`slidy` is the argument for the -t option and needs to come right after it.