# Batch converting Markdown files with Markdown.pl

Tags: bash, shell, markdown

Referencing a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754/how-can-i-convert-markdown-documents-to-html-en-masse), but still having difficulties converting my folder of .md files:

```
for i in src/*.md; do perl markdown/Markdown.pl --html4tags $i > output/${i%.*}.html; done;
```

Unfortunately (for my test file "index.md")it's throwing the error:

`line 11: output/src/index.html: No such file or directory`

I'm not sure how to get it to direct output to just "output/index.html".

Any thoughts? (I'm not interested in using another soluton like pandoc, just trying to do this in bash)

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of `src/*.md` will yield elements that all start with `src/`.  You can remove the path of a file, yield only the filename sans directory, with  `dirname`.

Since you're using the ${variable%match} replacement pattern to replace `.md` with `.html`, it would probably be easiest to create a new variable, here `$j`, to hold the results of `basename`.

```
for i in src/*.md; do j="$(basename $i)"; perl markdown/Markdown.pl --html4tags $i > output/${j%.*}.html; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that the directory `output/src`, relative to the working directory in which the command is executed, does not exist. You can do a

```
mkdir -p output/src; for i in ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `for` loop, take advantage of modern multi-core CPUs, test what its going to do in advance without actually doing anything and get everything done in parallel with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --dry-run perl markdown/Markdown.pl --html4tags {} \> output/{/.}.html ::: src/*md
```

**Sample Output**

```
perl markdown/Markdown.pl --html4tags src/a.md > output/a.html
```

If that looks correct, run it again but without the `--dry-run` to do it for real.